# Simple guessing game error

Tags: java, debugging, lc3

Ok so first this is the description of the program: The program will simulate a simple guessing game. The answer to the guessing game will always be 6.
The program will continually ask the user to guess a number between 0 and 9. The user enters the guess from the keyboard.
If the guess is larger than 6; the program should output:
Too big.
If the guess is smaller than 6; the program should output:
Too small.
When the user finally guesses correctly, the program will output:
Correct! You took # guesses.
where # is the number of guesses it took the user.
If after 9 guesses, the user has not correctly guessed the number, the program should output:Game over. Correct answer is 6.
You do not need to check for invalid input (alphabetical characters, punctuation, etc).

This is the error i'm receiving: Line 43: Expected label or 9 bit signed PC offset, but found 'R3' instead.
And here's my code:

```
.ORIG X3000

LD R2, SIX
LD R3, COUNTER

IN
ADD R1, R0, #0
ADD R0, R1, R2
BRn TOOLOW
BRp TOOHIGH
BRz GG

AGAIN:
IN
ADD R1, R0, #0
ADD R0, R1, R2
BRn TOOLOW
BRp TOOHIGH
BRz GG

TOOLOW:
LEA R0, LOW
PUTS
ADD R1, R0, #0
ADD R3, R3, #1
ADD R0, R3, #-9
BRn AGAIN
BRz LOSE

TOOHIGH:
LEA R0, HIGH
PUTS
ADD R1, R0, #0
ADD R3, R3, #1
ADD R0, R3, #-9
BRn AGAIN
BRz LOSE

GG:
ADD R3, R3, #1
LEA R0, WIN
PUTS
LEA R0, R3
PUTS
LEA R0, WIN2
PUTS
HALT

LOSE:
LEA R0, GAMEOVER 
PUTS
HALT

SIX .FILL #-54
COUNTER .FILL #0
LOW .STRINGZ "Too small."
HIGH .STRINGZ "Too big."
WIN .STRINGZ "Correct! You took "
WIN2 .STRINGZ " guesses."
GAMEOVER .STRINGZ "Game over. Correct answer is 6."

.END
```

So how can I fix the error?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is pointing to this line

`LEA R0, R3`

Your program is trying to use register R3 like a label and the assembler won't allow it.

If you want to move the value stored in R3 into R0, you will need to do something like the following:

```
AND R3, R3, #0    ; clear R3
ADD R3, R3, R0    ; store the value in R0 into R3
```